# Javascript Promises on Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't familiar with JavaScript Promises function.

Currently I have this code on my Angular Controller

```
$http.get('pages/about.html').then(function(response) {
    var raw_html = response.data;
    $scope.aboutHTML = raw_html.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
});
```

I want to re-write the code so I could do something like this

```
$scope.indexHTML = getHTML('pages/index.html');
$scope.aboutHTML = getHTML('pages/about.html');
...
```

with function like this

```
function getHTML(url){
    $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        var raw_html = response.data;
        return = raw_html.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
    });
}
```

How to write the the code properly for the function above?

**[Update #1]**

Temporary Solution by [@charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl)

```
function getHTML(url){
    // return the promise
    return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        var raw_html = response.data.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
        return  raw_html;
    });
}

getHTML('pages/index.html').then(function(raw_html){
    $scope.indexHTML = raw_html;
});
```

I wanna to write this function to reduce the manual work, with this way I still need to write down $scope.{page} for each page, so anyone know better way?

**[Update #2]**

Solution by [@joeytwiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/99777/joeytwiddle)

```
function getHTML(url){
    // return the promise
    return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        var raw_html = response.data.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
        return  raw_html;
    });
}

getHTML('pages/index.html').then(function(raw_html){
    $scope.indexHTML = raw_html;
});
```

Comment: If you are using *angular ui router* there's a *clean* way to achieve this using `resolve`. If you are using the ui router then check this out: http://bguiz.github.io/js-standards/angularjs/resolving-promises-for-a-controller/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to just return the result, because the result will not be available until some time in the future.  #asynchronous

You can only handle the result using a callback function.

If you want to minimize the work from outside, I would suggest something like this:

```
getHTMLAndStore('pages/index.html', $scope, 'indexHTML');
getHTMLAndStore('pages/about.html', $scope, 'aboutHTML');

function getHTMLAndStore(url, object, property) {
    $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        var raw_html = response.data;
        var weird_html = raw_html.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
        object[property] = weird_html;
    }).catch(console.error.apply(console));
}
```

This is pure JS and not really related to Angular.

Note that these two requests will fire in parallel, not in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

`$http` returns a promise so you need to return that promise from the function and use another `then()` to assign the scope variable:

```
function getHTML(url){
    // return the promise
    return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        var raw_html = response.data.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
        return  raw_html;
    });
}

getHTML('pages/index.html').then(function(raw_html){
    $scope.indexHTML = raw_html;
});
```

Currently your function doesn't return anything

Comment: No... You can't return an asynchronous data response from a function